# What event categories and actions in Google Analytics SDK iOS?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am reading [this guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/events) on the Google Developers website to set up custom events management in my iOS app. Specifically, I want to be able to track certain custom events such as "User has finished a certain action" or "User has tapped the search button".

In some cases I could rely on automatic screen measurement, but I want to be able to track some specific events according to my preferences, and I have been trying to set them up through custom events:

```
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"     // Event category (required)
                                                      action:@"button_press"  // Event action (required)
                                                       label:@"play"          // Event label
                                                       value:nil] build]];    // Event value
```

What I don't understand is if there is a set of allowed values for Category and Action (and in this case, where?), or if I can specify whatever NSString I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set any thing you want for the values of Category Action Label (and if you want to add  Value, that needs to be a number).

But here is a good way of thinking about it that I like to use:

- category - what is it? for example: video, button, tab
- action - what did they do? example: play, pause, press, click
- label - what is a unique identifier under the category? example: welcome video, home button, tab 2

Then it makes it a lot easier to dig into when you are analyzing the data.